# How to use a tty as a sound device for pjsua?

Tags: python, sip

I have a bi-directional PCM device that appears as /dev/ttyUSBxx. It provides and consumes 16-bit linear PCM at 8KHz (though that can be changed to u-LAW or a-LAW). I would like to use the device in conjunction with pjsua to create a VoIP application, so that the python SIP [hello world](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Hello_World) example works with it.

How?